# Roslyn scripting entry point?

Tags: c#, roslyn, blazor-webassembly

I am building a REPL interface with Blazor webassembly.

I have build a textarea where you can write code. The code compiles successfully. The problem is that the textarea is empty. Normally, as a C# developer, you would see an entry point (the Main method) by which the program starts.

How do I fix that?

[Try dotnet](https://try.dot.net/) is an good example of what I want to achieve. In my case the textarea is empty, but I can program in there. Not sure what the entry point is in my case.

I am really stuck here since I cannot find much about Roslyn scripting with Blazor.

Please help me out.

My code to compile input:

```
private ScriptState _scriptState = null;
    private StringWriter _sw;
    private string _output;

    public ChallengeCompiler()
    {
        _sw = new StringWriter();
        Console.SetOut(_sw);
        Console.SetError(_sw);
    }

    public string CompileCode(string input)
    {
        string[] references =
        {
            "System",
            "System.Collections",
            "System.Collections.Generic",
            "System.Collections.Concurrent",
            "System.Console",
            "System.Diagnostics.Debug",
            "System.Diagnostics.Process",
            "System.Diagnostics.StackTrace",
            "System.Globalization",
            "System.IO",
            "System.Reflection",
            "System.Runtime",
            "System.Runtime.InteropServices",
            "System.Text",
            "System.Text.Encoding",
            "System.Text.RegularExpressions",
            "System.Threading",
            "System.Threading.Tasks",
            "System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel",
            "System.Threading.Thread",
            "System.ValueTuple",
        };

        try
        {
            if (_scriptState == null)
            {
                _scriptState = CSharpScript.RunAsync(input, ScriptOptions.Default.WithImports(references)).Result;
            }
            else
            {
                _scriptState = _scriptState.ContinueWithAsync(input).Result;
            }

            if (_scriptState.ReturnValue != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_scriptState.ReturnValue.ToString()))
            {
                _output = _scriptState.ReturnValue.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                _output = _sw.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (CompilationErrorException e)
        {
            _output = "-----------------------------------\n";
            _output += string.Join(Environment.NewLine, e.Diagnostics);
        }

        return _output;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If you open "try.dot.net", see that the example code contains a "Main" method, which is the entry point. Why can't you define your own "Main" method in the code in your textarea?

Comment: You just construct the default methods yourself as text and set that as the default content in the text area

Comment: How do I do that? Where do I find that information?

Comment: What information do you need?

Comment: How I can set the defaults for the main method. Setting that code in the textarea won't work. I don't know the entry point since I can just write methods and execute them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "default for the main method". What defaults are you referring to? The entry point is always a static method called `Main` in C#

Comment: I don't necessarily mean default method but I want to know how to make my script run from the Main method like the given example in the post. In my application I can just create classes anywhere. There is no entry point from where I must start.